# A problem of minimizing distance.

Tags: calculus, optimization

A power house, P, is on one bank of a straight river $200$ m wide, 
and a factory, F, is on the opposite bank $400m$ downstream from P. 
The cable has to be taken across the river,
under water at a cost of Rs $6/m$. 
On land the cost is Rs $ 3/m$. 
What path should be chosen so that the cost is minimized?

I first looked at the extreme cases and then tried to find the solution. But then too there was a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture. Let $A$ be the point directly across the river from $P$.

Suppose we go underwater directly to a point $x$ metres downstream from $P$. Then by the Pythagorean Theorem, we will have a $\sqrt{x^2+200^2}$ underwater stretch. Then we need to travel $400-x$ overland to $F$. The cost $C(x)$ is given by
$$C(x)=6\sqrt{x^2+200^2}+3(400-x).$$
To minimize, find the derivative $C'(x)$ and set it equal to $0$. We have
$$C'(x)=\frac{6x}{\sqrt{x^2+200^2}}-3.$$
Solving $C'(x)=0$ is easy. We get $2x=\sqrt{x^2+200^2}$. Square both sides.

When you have done this, and found a candidate $x$,  you need to check whether this really gives the minimum cost.

**Remark:** There are various other ways to solve the problem. We chose the most basic beginning calculus approach.